# Make Infowindow Smaller

Tags: maps, infowindow

How can I change the size of the infowindow, about half the width, in my maps? Also I need to change the font and font color.

[www.driftcoffeehouse.com](http://www.driftcoffeehouse.com)

When I place this code in my home.php, my map does not show.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString,
maxWidth: 10%  
});
```

Comment: for width use property `maxWidth`. For font and color use CSS styling.

Comment: Should the maxWidth value be in px or percentage?

Comment: It is specified as a number. I think it means width in pixels.

Comment: When I place anything less than 100 the map does not load on my homepage. Anything over 100 doesn't change the info window at all.

Comment: Last option from object literal should be without comma. `maxWidth: 100,` should be `maxWidth: 100`. The same for map options...